# 'Version is not ready' error on update - GAE Python

Tags: google-app-engine

I am unable to update my frontends nor my backends. I get the error message 'Version is not ready'. This bug has persisted for coming up to 24 hours now. I have a task perpetually running in a queue. My best guess is that this task is stopping the update. I am unable to delete the task as it is perpetually running, nor can I delete the queue as I am unable to upload a new queue.yaml definition. The same task previously failed due to a maximum recursion error as I had a synchronous RPC within an asynchronous tasklet.

I'm pretty sure the fix will require someone from the GAE side forcibly resetting the task queue. Thus, this question would be more suitably directed to the GAE team with details about my app in a less public forum. Though, from what I can see, they [do not allow direct support questions and suggest posting the question here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/community). My follow up question, then, is when you have a GAE issue that requires action from the GAE team - how do you get hold of them (other than paying US$500/month for a premium support account)?

EDIT:

The task is/was meant to be running on a backend instance. I intended to shutdown all backend and frontend instances via the console assuming that they would cancel the task and restart themselves. But I found that only one frontend instance was running - no backends. After shutting down that frontend instance, the dashboard has reported that I have 0 instances running, yet the website is still serving and the task remains perpetually running.

EDIT:

Disabling the app stopped the task from running. After reenabling the app, I was able to update it. Though I am left with a [ghost task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330455/gae-ghost-task-in-the-machine) in my queue.

Comment: Can you just suspend the queue in question; click on it from the app engine admin and press pause.

Comment: I paused it for about an hour to no avail. In the 'Running' column, the console reported "1 (paused)". I resumed the queue in the hope that the task would complete or fail and then be deleted. That was about 19 hours ago.

Comment: You could pause your queue and shut down the instance running that task. Not pleasant, but perhaps would stop it from being "running"? You can shut down individual instances from the "Instances" panel.

Comment: If the site is still serving, are you getting logs? What do they say about instance ID? Perhaps there's an instance running of a different version? What about going all-out and disabling the application?

Comment: How do I disable the app and will the data in the datastore be okay? I found one reference to an instance ID in the logs. There was a request to /initc with a 404 response about 15min ago. When I clicked on the instance ID link in the log, I was taken to the instances panel and greeted with with message "Could not find specified instance with key".

Comment: You disable the app under application settings. Disabling the app will not affect your data in any way; it's safe.

Comment: Okay, app is disabled, site is not serving - task is still running. This guy seems to have the sticking power of a cockroach in an atomic bomb.

Comment: Hold the press, the task is gone! Now, lets see if I can update ...

Comment: I can now update my app again. If you put your suggestion to disable the app in an answer, I will mark it as the correct one. According to https://appengine.google.com/queues the task is still in the queue, but not running. According to https://appengine.google.com/queuedetails it is no longer in the queue. But that is a separate issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a stuck task queue job, I'd try disabling the queue and killing the instance running that job. If that doesn't work, I'd try disabling the app temporarily.